# Binding to an Object when Using WebForms WebMethods

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, webmethod

I am trying to bind to a class when using a WebMethod in a WebForms app but I am getting the following error:

`` {
"Message":"Invalidwebservicecall,missingvalueforparameter:\u0027dto\u0027.",
"StackTrace":"atSystem.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Objecttarget,IDictionary2parameters)
atSystem.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Objecttarget,IDictionary2parameters)
atSystem.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContextcontext,WebServiceMethodDatamethodData,IDictionary`2rawParams)
atSystem.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContextcontext,WebServiceMethodDatamethodData)",
"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"
} ``

However if I use 3 separate string properties, the call succeeds with no errors. My issue with that is that the object has potentially 20+ properties and I dont fancy a method signature that long (not to mention they could quite easily change).

WebMethod

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class FooService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<FooDTO> Test(FooDTO dto)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(dto != null, "Oops, the dto is null");
        return null;
    }
}
```

jQuery used to call the method

```
var dto = {};
dto.Test1 = 'Ticket Number';
dto.Test2 = 'Title';
dto.Test3 = true;

$.ajax({
    url: '/service/FooService.asmx/Test',
    data: JSON.stringify(dto),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        alert('hooray!');
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('NOPE');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create another object and add your dto object as property.
Notice that the property should be with the same name  like your parameter in the web method.

```
var data = {};
data.dto = dto;
```

And then send your data object

```
$.ajax({
data: JSON.stringify(data),
type: 'POST',
....
```

Answer (score 0):

How about one parameter; you could use a library like JSON.NET which very easily parses it and converts it back to an object again; all you would need to do is ensure it comes over to the server as a string, which that string is JSON content.

Answer (score 0):

remove JSON.stringify if you are using POST method

```
$.ajax({
    data: dto,
    type: 'POST',
    ....
});
```